# How can I set the physical path of this xml file programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, path

I have my hibernate.cfg.xml congif file placed in PersistenceManager project as you see in the picture.

[image]

And I need programmatically to set the physical path to this configuration file in this getter to configure NHibernate (the line with cfg.Configure ):

```
public class SessionService
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory = null;
    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
                string fullPath = (new SessionService()).GetType().Assembly.Location;

                cfg.Configure(@"the working path to hibernate.cfg.xml");

                //I will Add Mapping directives here

                _sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
            }

            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do it safely just by typing the string "hibernate.cfg.xml" and letting the C# to generate the rest of the physical path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the properties window for the file, set the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer". It should then be found by the `Configure` method without adding a path (just the filename).

**Edit:** To get the full path at runtime, you can try this:

```
cfg.Configure(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), @"hibernate.cfg.xml"));
```

Comment: That should work as long as the application's working directory is set to its own directory. This might not be the case (e.g. when running as a service or from autostart) so adding the executable's path won't harm.

Comment: @Mario: But how can I do it programmatically?

Comment: To get the application's path just evaluate 'Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)'.

Comment: Mario's suggestion is also good, but it requires you to add a reference to the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly if you don't have it in your code base yet.